# Pandas how can I do a wildcard search on entire dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I'm working on and trying to find a specific value that is impacting my analysis. Apparently there is a cell with a value "<" in it and I'm struggling to find the specific cell.

I tried this:

```
print(df[df.isin(['<'])].stack())
```

which I believe should show the value, except I believe this is searching for an exact match whereas I'm looking for a partial match.

How can I do a wild card search on the entire data frame?

Comment: can you try `s = df.stack().str.contains('<')` then `s[s].index`

Comment: @anky Thank you - I got a error - ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: My bad, I sould have addressed that, you might have NaN values somewhere replace `s` with `s = df.stack().str.contains('<',na=False)`

Comment: @anky Thank you, it worked like a charm. Cool thing about your solution is I have all the options of contains so I made the search case insensitive. Can you do me a favor and put this as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: on a second thought, I am wondering how did it give you an na error when stack() drops the NaN entries by default :) did you pass `df.stack(dropna=False)` ? by any chance..

Comment: @anky No I simply copied your command and ran it without modifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For partial matches, use instead of `isin` , [`series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `na=false` for handling `NaN` values(*also check the other paremeters*) and also if using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) , do the stack first and then find the indexes with `boolean indexing` which will give you the rows and column labels where the condition matches:

```
s = df.stack().str.contains('<',na=False)
output_indices = s[s].index
```